# is memmove necessary for trim function in C?

Tags: c, trim, memmove

I was reading a [wikipedia article on Trimming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimming_%28computer_programming%29) and saw this implementation of ltrim (left trim)

```
char *
ltrim(char *str)
{
  char *ptr;
  int  len;

  for (ptr = str; *ptr && isspace((int)*ptr); ++ptr);

  len = strlen(ptr);
  memmove(str, ptr, len + 1);

  return str;
}
```

Would bad things happen if I skip memmove and return ptr isntead?

```
char *
ltrim(char *str)
{
  char *ptr;
  int  len;

  for (ptr = str; *ptr && isspace((int)*ptr); ++ptr);

  return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you return `ptr` -- i.e., a pointer value other than the original pointer --  and if that pointer is the only pointer to the original memory block, then no one will be able to `free()` it, and there will be a memory leak. You can't call `free()` on a pointer into the middle of an allocated block, but only on a pointer to the beginning of the block -- i.e., only on a pointer originally returned by `malloc()`.

If for some reason you can be sure that a pointer to the original block will be preserved, or the block will never need to be freed, then the `memmove()` isn't needed; but those are bad assumptions for a general purpose utility routine.

Comment: Since it mutates the contents of the original pointer and returns the original pointer... I believe the return type should be `void`. It's misleading otherwise.

Comment: @trinithis -- I dunno. What about being able to write something like `char * ptr = ltrim(rtrim(getline()))` ?

Answer (score 3):

Biggest problem: **This is not the way `ltrim()` is expected to work.**

`ltrim()` is expected to have a side effect, to change the string *in place*.

For example,

```
char *a = " hello";
trim(a);
printf(a);
```

Would be expected to print `"hello"`, but without `memmove()` it won't.

**Edited to add:**

A comment below reasonably asks, "Expected by *who?*"

In a language with automatic garbage collection, I expect string functions to return a *new* string with the desired transformation.

For those without it (which is the case here), I expect them to change the string *in place*, sometimes returning a pointer to the result, sometimes not.

So perhaps I should have said: **This is not the way C functions are expected to work.**

Comment: Expected by *who*? It may work this way in some languages, but it doesn't in most. [Here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/code/216919/implementing-string-trimming-ltrim-and-rtrim-in-c) is the first Google hit for "ltrim C", and the implementation shown there returns a new pointer to the unmodified original data. In fact, to implement your version in C, the argument would have to be pointer-to-pointer-to-char, and so it couldn't even be called the way you've shown above, and the fact that you couldn't  call it on an rvalue would be an immense pain.

Comment: I don't understand Ernest's statement that the argument would have to be pointer-to-pointer-to-char.  If the input string is not modified by `ltrim`, then the call to `ltrim` can be easily replaced by a simple `s += strspn (s, " \t\f\r\n") ;` with whatever characters you want as whitespace.

Comment: In other words, you're saying the `memmove()` is, indeed, required -- it would help to state that explicitly.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill - ah, now I see what you were asking. Fixed, I think.